# Java Copy files into zip AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, multithreading, file, java-8, zip

### The Description:

I've created a ZIP file in Java 8 and try to copy a directory with all it's subfiles and directories into this zip file.

```
   Path directory = Paths.get("P:\Java\Test\backups\test.zip");
   // path to the world;
   Path world = Paths.get("P:\Java\Test\world");
   
   [...]
   
    // Create a map which tells the file system to create a new file if it doesn't exist
    ImmutableMap immutableMap = ImmutableMap.of("create", String.valueOf(Files.notExists(this.directory)));
    
    // Get a file system provider which is capable of creating a ZIP file
    FileSystemProvider zipProvider = FileSystemProvider.installedProviders().stream()
            .filter(provider -> provider.getScheme().equals("jar")).findFirst().get();
    
    // Create the file system
    try (FileSystem fs = zipProvider.newFileSystem(this.directory, immutableMap)) {
        
        try {
            Files.walk(this.world).forEach((Path sourcePath) -> {
                try {
                CopyOption[] option = new CopyOption[] {
                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
                };
                Path destination = this.directory.resolve(this.world.relativize(sourcePath));
                Files.copy(sourcePath, destination,option);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

### The Problem:

Whenever I add the line `Files.copy` to copy my directory and all sub-directories and sub-files into the zip file I'm getting the following exception: `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: .\backups\test.zip`

### Console output:

In the following stacktrace I changed the line numbers of the class calls to the one's of the code snippet I posted above for better readability except for the call to the `ThreadBackup.run` method. It is basically the method the code is beeing executed in with some other, but unrelated things.

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: .\backups\tests.zip
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:231)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1274)
    at serverutilities.backups.ThreadBackups.lambda$createZipFile$1(ThreadBackups.java:24)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at serverutilities.backups.ThreadBackups.createZipFile(ThreadBackups.java:18)
    at serverutilities.backups.ThreadBackups.run(ThreadBackups.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: P:\Java\Test\backups\test.zip
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:90)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsLinkSupport.getRealPath(WindowsLinkSupport.java:259)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:836)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(WindowsPath.java:44)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.removeFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:322)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.close(ZipFileSystem.java:305)
    at serverutilities.backups.ThreadBackups.createZipFile(ThreadBackups.java:32)
    at serverutilities.backups.ThreadBackups.run(ThreadBackups.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I noticed that whenever I call the `Files.copy` method the ZIP file isn't even created or atleast not saved, thus the `NoSuchFileException` is thrown after the `AccessDeniedException` is thrown for every directory and file I try to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a regular file as a directory.

In this line

```
try (FileSystem fs = zipProvider.newFileSystem(this.directory, immutableMap)) {
```

you are opening or creating a zip file system at `this.directory`, which must be a valid path within the *default* file system. After succeeding, `this.directory` definitely is a *regular* file (in the zip file format), still within the default file system.

This line

```
Path destination = this.directory.resolve(this.world.relativize(sourcePath));
```

is treating this regular file like a directory.

You want to copy into the zip file system, hence you must use a path from the zip file system, not the path to the zip file within the default file system.

You may get the root of the zip filesystem, e.g.

```
Path zipRoot = fs.getPath("/");
```

and use this as target. As far as I know, you can’t use the `Path` retrieved from one file system as argument to a method of the `Path` of another file system, so you would have to resolve the target path like

```
Path destination = zipRoot;
for(Path p: this.world.relativize(sourcePath))
    destination = destination.resolve(p.toString());
```

But perhaps there is a simpler method.

---

Another issue is the use of `Files.copy` for directories. When the directory already exists (and the root directory always exists), it will fail, unless you specify `REPLACE_EXISTING`, but this will fail as soon as the target directory is not empty. This simplest solution is to keep existing directories as-is, so the code would look like

```
try(FileSystem fs = zipProvider.newFileSystem(this.directory, immutableMap)) {
    Path zipRoot = fs.getPath("/");
    CopyOption[] option = {
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
    };
    Files.walk(this.world).forEach(sourcePath -> {
        try {
            Path destination = zipRoot;
            for(Path p: this.world.relativize(sourcePath))
                destination = destination.resolve(p.toString());
            if(!Files.isDirectory(destination) || !Files.isDirectory(sourcePath))
                Files.copy(sourcePath, destination, option);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    });
} catch(IOException|UncheckedIOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // TODO replace with actual exception handling
}
```

This will skip path entries, if the target directory exists *and* the source also is a directory, as situations where the source is not a directory but the target is an existing directory should be reported via exception.

If you want to enforce the policy of replacing existing files and directories, you would have to implement a tree deletion for the case that there is an existing non-empty directory, but still, you have to skip the root directory, which can’t be deleted.

Comment: This nearly works for me, thought I'm getting some exceptions: `java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /` and `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: .\backups\tests.zip` and `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: .\backups\tests.zip`. This is my copy line: `Files.copy(sourcePath, destination);`. So with your way I'm no longer having my test.zip file, but about 4 to 5 temp files which hold all files which should have been copied into the zip file and can be opened using a tool like 7Zip. It would be great if you can edit your answer to provide a solution to this.

Comment: I have extended my answer. I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used java.nio.file, but once I had to deal with such task and I used java.util.zip, which is quite straightforward to use just for creating a zip file from a directory

Although, if you can't change what you are using for archiving the directory, then this solution won't be much of a help, but sample code with some explanations:

- Create new ZIP archive with new ZipOutputStream
- Walk through the file tree which is going to be zipped with Files.walk
- For each path of the file tree pack the entries. ZipEntry holds the metadata about a single file in the archive

To use it just call method packDir with Paths of src and the destination.zip

```
private static void packDir(Path src, Path dest) throws IOException {
    try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(dest));
         ZipOutputStream zo = new ZipOutputStream(out);
         Stream<Path> dirStream = Files.walk(src)) {
         dirStream.filter(p -> !p.equals(src)).forEach(path -> {
             try {
                 packEntry(src, zo, path);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         });
    }
}

private static void packEntry(Path src, ZipOutputStream zo, Path path) throws IOException {
    String name = src.relativize(path).toString().replace('\\', '/');
    boolean isDir = Files.isDirectory(path);
    if (isDir) {
        name += "/";
    }
    ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(name); 
    zo.putNextEntry(e);
    if (!isDir) {
        Files.copy(path, zo);
    }
    zo.closeEntry();
}
```

Comment: The best solution for me would be the one using java.nio.file, thought if I can't find a solution I will see whether I can change what I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I released some utility classes for adding and extracting files to/from JAR/ ZIP files using the NIO.2 File API.

Here's a snippet from the tutorial:

```
public void addResource(Path zipPath, Path targetDirPath, Path srcPath, String targetInZipPathString) throws IOException {  
    Path targetZipPath = copyZipFile(zipPath, targetDirPath);  

    try (FileSystem jarFS = JarFiles.newJarFileSystem(targetZipPath.toUri())) {  
        Path targetInZipPath = jarFS.getPath(targetInZipPathString);  

        // Adds the src directory name to the zip. You can omit this if you just want to copy the contents.  
        Path finalTargetInZipPath = PathUtils.resolve(targetInZipPath, srcPath.getFileName());  
        Files.createDirectories(finalTargetInZipPath);  

        CopyFileVisitor.copy(srcPath, finalTargetInZipPath);  
    }  
}
```

The [CopyFileVisitor](http://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/0.9/docs/site/apidocs/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/CopyFileVisitor.html) uses [PathUtils](http://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/0.9/docs/site/apidocs/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/PathUtils.html) to resolve Paths across FileSystems.

There is a [tutorial](http://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/0.9/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html#AddZipResourceSample).

The library is [Open Source](https://github.com/SoftSmithy/softsmithy-lib) and available from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```